# Design Patterns for Dynamic Inheritance

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, exception, metaprogramming

Here's what I'm trying to do, I'm not sure what to look for or what the proper way to design this is:

I'm working on an exception hierarchy for an application. As part of this, there are some exceptions which will sometimes be fatal and other times be recoverable -- whether a particular instance is fatal or recoverable is determined at runtime in the exception itself. For the purposes of organization I want to be able to do something like (I'm working in python):

```
try:
    mightThrowAnException()
except RecoverableException:
    handleThisException()
```

And then I'd have something like:

```
class MyException(...):
    ...
```

Where MyException could either take on FatalException or RecoverableException as a base class depending on what happens in the constructor.

I know I could have two separate exceptions `MyFatalException` and `MyRecoverableException` and then raise either one or there other in code but there are going to be a lot of different exceptions for different types of errors, which could be raised from multiple places in the code, and the exception has to do a few things like examine error logs to determine whether this instance should be fatal or not, so I think it makes sense to put all of this code into the exception handler itself.

So a couple of questions:

1. Given what I want to do, is this a good way to go about it, or is there a better design for this sort of thing?
2. I've read about class factories, but I don't see an easy way to dynamically change the base classes with such an approach, other things I've considered are metaclasses or overriding the excpetion's `__new__()` method and I'm not really sure what the pros and cons to each of these three approaches are. Are any of these the right approach or do I need something else?

Comment: Hmm. You know more about your particular needs than I do, but wouldn't it make more sense for the code which catches the exception to determine if it's fatal or not, on a case-by-case basis? How can you even handle a fatal exception, besides logging? The general problem is still interesting, though

Comment: I suspect I've dealt with something similar to what Jesse is describing in a Java project several years ago; it was an email gateway for our application.  Lots of error handling and recovery was added after the fact.  Since there was such a variety of possible (often generic) exception types, we ended up classify them as RetryableException and FastFailException and would just wrap whatever error occurred up in that, rather than declaring that exception as being thrown.  It worked out ok; Java's checked exceptions made it a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation is to decouple the exception's content from its meaning. The same exception can have different meanings in different places!

Your question suggests to turn an exception into a "sentient" object with advanced capabilities like examining logs. But this is not the intention for exceptions. Exceptions should be lightweight data objects, providing as much information as possible about *what happened*, but not determining on their own what should be done about it. The catching code does that, and as I said above, it's entirely conceivable that some exception will be handled in one way in some place, and in another way in some other place.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm not really sure about what sort of things should be handled in exceptions. Can you recommend any reading? Currently, I am only doing error logging in the exception. But the reason I want this is because I've got some code that talks to an unreliable server -- this should be allowed to fail occasionally, but I want the exception to examine my error logs and if this error seems to be occurring too frequently I need it to become fatal because something bigger might be wrong. Doing this in the exception seemed like the logical place, do you think it's not?

Comment: @Jesse, the exception is most definitely not the place to handle this sort of thing. The application should be the place to determine policy regarding an unreliable server. An exception is basically a message that something went wrong - it should not contain instructions on what do do, otherwise it's not an exception if there's a known course of action.

Comment: got it, thanks! this has convinced me that i need to refactor my code structure

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just go with a property to determine if an exception is fatal or not, if it's not possible to categorise a particular exception as either fatal or recoverable.

```
class MyBaseException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, ..., fatal=True):
        self.fatal = fatal

class MyException(MyBaseException):
    ...

try:
    do_something_that_raises()
except MyBaseException, e:
    if e.fatal:
        logging.error(e)
        raise
    else:
        recover_somehow(e)
```

The raiser of the exception should probably not tell listeners whether an exception is fatal or not however. They may be able to handle an exception deemed as fatal. The purposes of exceptions are to declare that something was wrong, and then let potential users determine whether they can recover from it, or not.